# Bootstrap accordion: how to make entire button clickable?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu, accordion, clickable

i add an accordion menu to my site, using this example:

```
<div class="bs-example">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">1. Menu number one</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Menu number one text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">2. Menu number two</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Menu number two</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">3. Menu number three</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Menu number three</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see it live [here](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=accordion)

Do you know how can i make the entire button clickable? At the moment just the title does it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create click event `.panel-heading` and in the event check if `.panel-heading` second ancestor is `<a class="" href="#colapseXXXXX" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse"></a>`. For example checking value in href. Then if it is true trigger click on the `<a>`.

Try this code:

```
$('.panel-heading').on('click', function () {
    var a = $(this).childen('.panel-title').children('a');
    var ahref = a.prop('href');
    if (ahref.indexOf('#collapse') > -1)
    {
        a.trigger("click");
    }
});
```

Working solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.panel-heading').on('click', function () {
        var a = $(this).find('a');
        var ahref = a.prop('href');
        if (ahref.indexOf('#collapse') > -1)
        {
            $('.panel-collapse').removeClass('in'); 
            $(this).next('div').addClass('in');
        }
    });

    $(".panel-heading a").on('click', function(event) { 
        $(this).closest('.panel-heading').trigger('click');
        return false;
    });

});;
```

Triggering click on  causing bubbling up click event back to .panel-heading and .panel-heading was triggering click on  again making infinite loop. If I try to preventDefault() I also prevent default bootstrap behavior so click didn't change anything. Solution above is the only one in my opinion.

Comment: Sorry, i am afraid i do not understand what you mean... can you add some more code?

Comment: When you said "ancestor"... did you mean "child" ?

Comment: Yes, sorry find "descendant"

Comment: I think i do my homework: http://pastebin.com/tZpSMaKF. Anyway none of these works except the first. What's wrong?

Comment: It doesn't work: `ahref.indexOf('#collapse')` seems to be always `-1`

Comment: Is var ahref defined? Please put your whole code to JS Fiddle to edit it quickly.

Comment: I tested it and seems not to work well. First if i want to close the menu the click doesn't work the second time. In addition, if you make few clicks on different heading then it finally brokes...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84580/discussion-between-xawery-wisniowiecki-and-smartmouse).

Comment: I tried to come in chat but i think you are offline. Anyway i changed your code, because in my case `href` property does not contain `collapse` string, so i removed the if condition at all. Please have a look and tell me if it is ok in my case: http://jsfiddle.net/5g60qLq2/43/

Answer (score 4):

Just a note,

Did you try to pull the a outside of the h4 class? 
so instead of

```
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">1. Menu number one</a>
        </h4>
    </div>
```

try

```
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
            <h4 class="panel-title">1. Menu number one</h4>
         </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: This works  perfectly! Is there any reason why we would not want to place a a header inside of a link? <a href="#"><h4>Header</h4></a> I

Comment: I wouldn't see any reason why not seems to work just fine

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but i had the same problem and solved it way easier.

Just give your ".panel-title a" a display of block

If the parents divs got padding, set it to 0 and set it to your .panel-title a instead

```
.panel-heading{
    padding: 0;
}

.panel-title a{
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

No need for .js here

Comment: Dude, this should have more votes! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but I faced exactly the same problem today using Bootstrap 4.

I followed the solution of hikups, but it is not necessary to use custom CSS.
Simply add d-block in the class attribute of the anchor element.

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" class="d-block">1. Menu number one</a>
```